# Typescript - why does generic dictionary type not return possibly undefined value?

Tags: typescript

Came across something really unexpected with Typescript

I've been using the following pattern to specify that an object is a dictionary of `string` keys to `Foo` values

`type Dictionary = { [id: string]: Foo }`

What's really strange is, when I try to retrieve a value from the Dictionary using *any* key, Typescript gives the return type as `Foo`

I would expect it to be `Foo | undefined`, as of course if the key does not map to any value, `undefined` is returned.

Here's an example of why this behaves unexpectedly - [see the playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAjAhgJwFxQB2ArgLYYQ5QC+AUKJFACICWAxsC3IbiMmlADaLACYEAzsBwtCAcwC6BeIjptukqFgKsOXHjj4p0tKKajcIBdNnxQAjDQA0UE2eAB3OFcy4CAJhoXOlo1Qg0sEREAeUIIABU4ACFcfgAKADMEJQQASmQAPihMuAA6GygAantaWgB6WqgAOUQGaEocOBxnLHEoCAAPSA4IEVosABtKYFSI6NiE5JwZkoscnLHJnGnZmPik3BnBAHILI-k1mqk+VFdTeqhE4mAodywWYGd3AAssYAB+KAACTg7igLF6wC+lGghBa4DaOA6VChOAgf1umk220iuwWBywJUhqIgFzMmKmMxx832SywxyJEAgZwu1CgbF+bC+UFS7TyNzJEwpRyi6TZcGIOHEEGckOhYN6WCIxHG4ygYDgMmAlD6iM6BCOlR1OHW1CAA)

```js
type Foo = { bar: number }
type Dictionary = { [id: string]: Foo }

const a: Dictionary = { 
  one: { bar: 1 }, 
  two: { bar: 2 } 
}

const addOneToBar = (foo: Foo) => foo.bar + 1

// No type error, maybe expected, because we 'know' from context that 
// the one property exists on the Dictionary instance a
alert(addOneToBar(a.one))
alert(addOneToBar(a['one']))

try {
  // There is still no type error here, though. Why?
  // Shouldn't a.three / a['three'] return Foo | undefined
  // instead of Foo, because we're not certain there is any three property?
  alert(addOneToBar(a.three))
  alert(addOneToBar(a['three']))
} catch (err) {
  alert('Of course, there is a null pointer error: ' + err)
}
```

This code seems to me to be obviously not typesafe, and indeed results in a runtime exception which is not flagged by Typescript.

I'm really surprised by this - returning `undefined` for a key pointing to nothing is a fundamental behaviour of Javascript objects, and I guess any generic dictionary/map implementation in most languages. I can't understand why Typescript would miss this.

Perhaps I've made a mistake in the code above, or I'm misinterpreting the purpose of the `{ [id: string]: Foo }` pattern, and/or there's another pattern for typing dictionaries in Typescript that does have this behaviour that I should use instead (I've already tried the `Record` type and found, again to my surprise, it also exhibits the same behaviour).

What is going on here?

---

**Edit**

I've just realised writing the question that I can probably do `type Dictionary = { [id: string]: Foo | undefined }` to get this behaviour. But again, why would this not be the default out of the box? Perhaps if you had a narrow key type, like an enum, it would make sense, but if you have a `string` key it's absolutely wrong to guarantee that a value will always be returned from the Dictionary, isn't it?

**Further Edit**

As in the comments, I've now realised that Typescript behaving this way actually makes sense, and the solution above, to **explicitly** tell TS that the dictionary may return undefined values is the solution. In a sense, this is me assuming that TS should infer things from types rather than me having to explicitly state them - you could argue the convenience case either way - the way I proposed it should behave is good for when keys might be missing, but bad for when you're sure they won't be. The opposite is true for the way TS actually behaves here.

---

**Mods**

This isn't a question with an answer per-se (TypeScript is just working as designed), but I'm going to leave it around unless it gets close votes because I think it's an interesting summary of the behaviour and why is is implemented in the way it is.

Comment: Your edit shows the solution. And in your playground you see the reason why i think they didn't implement it that way. because the code where you wrote `// No type error, as expected` will lead to a type error (correctly so).

Comment: You're right. I've thought about it more and realised I was looking at it in the wrong way. I'm effectively saying that I think TS is not being pedantic enough about correctness, but actually it is - it's behaving exactly correctly according to what I've specified in the type and trusting me. If I want TS to make the `| undefined` assumption, I have to tell it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `type Dictionary = { [id: string]: Foo }`, you are telling the compiler that any string is a valid key for this type. The compiler will then make no assumptions about which strings are valid keys and which are not, essentially saying that any property accessor is defined and will return a `Foo`.

If you want to enforce that only the `one` and `two` keys are defined for your object, then you can strictly define the properties of your dictionary:

```
type Dictionary = {
  one: Foo;
  two: Foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right - as in the comments above the mistaken assumption is that TS should infer something not explicitly stated in my type definition. It is actually doing exactly as I say. The solution is to explicitly tell it to expect values of Foo **or** undefined from the Dictionary, then it takes my assumption into account. Just making a strict type isn't quite the right solution here, as it's really about making a dictionary object I can use any keys with at runtime -- the one, two props thing in the example was just to illustrate the issue - probably didn't make that clear enough.